# AWS S3 Delegate Methods Interrupted on iPhone

Tags: iphone, arrays, delegates, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I use the following three delegate methods to pull images from S3. They are called in the presented order.

```
-(void)request:(AmazonServiceRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response;
-(void)request:(AmazonServiceRequest *)request didReceiveData:(NSData *)data;
-(void)request:(AmazonServiceRequest *)request didCompleteWithResponse:(AmazonServiceResponse *)response;
```

I've noticed that if an image is large that sometimes the didReceieveResponse will get called before the previous didCompleteWithResponse has finished. This screws up the NSData received in the second delegate.

How do I fix this? All three are getting called in a for statement iteration for each iteration. like so:

```
for (NSString *name in array){
        @try {
    S3GetObjectRequest *gor = [[S3GetObjectRequest alloc]initWithKey:name withBucket:[Constants pictureBucket]];
    [gor setDelegate:self];
    [s3 getObject:gor];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not worked with S3 but I am sure that there would be some way of distinguishing the three different `AmazonServiceRequest *request` in the delegate functions(maybe the key you are using to `init` ). So you can take whatever action you are doing with the `NSData` by first making a check on the `request` you are getting back in the delegate functions

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand that. You're saying write each request to check on the previous one before starting? How would I do that?

Comment: @Eric suppose you want to save the response of all the three requests(or whatever action you want with the NSData), maintain three NSData object, say NSData *data1, data2,data3. Now in your delegate method, check if(request is firstRequest){ [data1 appendYourData]} else if(request is secondRequest) {.....etc  . The wholde point is before doing something with the response NSData check to which request it belong

Comment: I guess my question is do I have to do that? WHy can't each delegate be associated with a single instance of that data object?

Comment: Well, in the `for` loop, for all the three `S3GetObjectRequest` you are setting the delegate to `self`. i.e all three request objects share the same delegate. So the only way the delegate can distinguish is by checking the request object which it receive as its parameter. I hope it is clear now